# c string tokenization question

Tags: c, string

```
char *str = malloc (14);
sprintf(str, "%s", "one|two|three");

char *token1, *token2, *token3;
char *start = str;

token1 = str;
char *end = strchr (str, '|');
str = end + 1;
end = '\0';

token2 = str;
end = strchr (str, '|');
str = end + 1;
end = '\0';

...

free(start);
```

does that free work properly since I have been setting bytes within str to null in order to tokenize it?

Comment: It is good practice to use the same variable name for the malloc and the free.  In this case, use "start" for the malloc, and then assign "str" to the value of "start".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it works, free does not care where the null termination is.  Or even if there is one.  You can use malloc/free for any type of data not only null terminated strings.

Answer (score 3):

the free doesn't check the contents of the data. So yes this is correct